# How do I move my text to a fixed/specific position?

Tags: html-table, html-email

I am creating an email that has 2 sections of text, 2 images and a button in the middle. I am able to move the images into a fixed position just fine, but with text I only know how to move it left, center, or right. I basically want the text in between that. For example the first section of text I want it in between center and right.

Here is the Code:

```
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
               <tbody>
<tr>
<td class="img" style="font-size: 0pt; line-height: 0pt; text-align: Center; width: 20px;"> </td>
<td>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<div align="center">
<td valign="top" class="column-280" style="width: 200px;">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; BOTTOM:-5px; LEFT:125px; WIDTH:125px; HEIGHT:150px" <img src="https://qa.travelinsured.com/images/email/red-clock.png?Status=Temp&sfvrsn=2" alt="Pete's Promise Badge" height="150" width="150" align="Right">
             <div style="font-size: 0pt; line-height: 0pt; height: 12px;"><img alt="" width="1" height="12" src="http://www2.travelinsured.com/rs/travelinsured/images/empty.gif" style="height: 12px;" /></div>
                         <p> <div style="color: #656565; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; text-align: Center;">Time is running out!</p><br><p>There's still time to vote!</p><br><p>Please vote for Travel Insured's<br>Agent Loyalty Program today!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position as well as bottom, left, right, etc. all are not very consistent across clients and major clients like Outlook, Gmail and Yahoo do not support them at all. (ref: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Your best bet is to use tables for all layouts.  This means using nested tables as well as tds and padding to specify locations. It is not forgiving nor easily transferred to a mobile view, but for as close to an exact positioning need as you can get, it is really the only way to create it consistently across clients.